# Two equivalent definitions of Radon measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $\Omega$ be a (for my purposes: locally compact) Hausdorff space. Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\Omega$ and let $A\subset\Omega$ be a Borel set.

- $\mu$ is called *locally finite* if $\mu(K)<\infty$ for all compact $K\subset\Omega$.
- $\mu$ is called *inner regular* on $A$ if $$\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset A \ \text{compact}\}.$$
- $\mu$ is called *outer regular* on $A$ if $$\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(U):U\supset A \ \text{open}\}.$$

According to [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Radon+measure) article, the following two definitions are equivalent:

> **Definition 1.** A borel measure $\mu$ is a *Radon measure* if $\mu$ is locally finite and inner regular on all **Borel** sets.

> **Definition 2.** A Borel measure $\mu$ is a *Radon measure* if $\mu$ is locally finite, inner regular on all **open** sets and outer regular on all **Borel** sets.

Why are these definitions equivalent? [Here](https://planetmath.org/RadonMeasure) is another article discussing these two definitions.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103208/relations-between-various-definitions-of-a-radon-measure?rq=1

Comment: The second measure described in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/215261/30222 seems to satisfy 2 but not 1. The main issue is that you might have a set of infinite measure whose all subsets have either infinite or uniformly bounded measure, even if there is no such open set. You can get rid of this by e.g. assuming more additivity (not just countable), $\sigma$-finiteness or second countability.

Comment: The first example satisfies 1 but not 2, also: you might have a null set whose all open supersets have infinite measure.

Comment: @tomasz At first glance it does indeed answer my question. Thank you!