# Equivalence of inner and outer Radon measures on $\sigma$-compact lcH spaces

Tags: measure-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103208/relations-between-various-definitions-of-a-radon-measure) differences between definitions of Radon measures were discussed. In particular, for $\sigma$-compact lcH spaces inner and outer regular locally finite Borel measures are equivalent. As a proof [these lecture notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Emjunge/54115/arv.pdf)(Prop. 1.1.) were linked. I do understand the implication "outer regularity implies inner regularity", however in the proof of the converse, it was stated that given a measurable bounded (i.e. contained in a compact set) set $A$ has compact closure (that's clear) and that one could find an open bounded superset of the closure of $A$ by "a simple covering argument" which is what I don't understand.

What you could do is find an open cover of $\overline{A}$, the existence of which is ensured by local finiteness of the measure space, which could be reduced to a finite subcover by compactness. However these open covering sets need not be bounded, at least I don't see why. I thought of restricting to the subspace topology on the compact superspace in which $A$ and $\overline{A}$ lie by boundedness but then I would get boundedness only in the subspace. Constructing the cover in such a way that it lies completely in the compact superset would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arvind defines

> A set is called bounded if it is contained in
> some compact set,

immediately before the proposition.

The definition of "locally compact Hausdorff" is not given in Arvind's text, but the standard definition is

> A space is locally compact if every point has a neighborhood contained in a compact set.

That is, $X$ is locally compact is every point has a neighborhood that is bounded (in Arvind's sense).

For each point in $\overline{A}$, pick such a set.  That's your bounded open cover.